# Spring, create a bean from deserializing

Tags: java, spring

I've not used Spring too much, so I might be missing something obvious. Anyway, this is the question:

Say you have a Spring managed bean that is a networking client. After you call a method on it you get some object back, say it is a List

Now I want to process that List into something more useful for the rest of my application, say it is of a MyBusinessBean type.

How do I avoid doing a

```
new MyBusinessBean(List<String> info)
```

?? If I do this it becomes an object that is not part of the context.

I'm doing something like:

```
MyBusinessBean myBean = (MyBusinessBean) applicationContext.getBean("myBusinessBean", info);
```

However I keep reading everywhere that this is a signal of something not being done properly, since I am making my code context aware. What is the proper Spring way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way is what you do in Spring.  Calling "new" means you're breaking the model.

But don't assume that every call to "new" is eliminated by Spring.  Every object need not be under Spring's control.  Sometimes you just gotta call "new", usually in the scope of a single method.  Create the object, use it, GC it - no Spring bean factory needed.

If you want to give an object in your app access to that List after serialization, simply pass the reference.  You don't need the Spring bean factory in the situation you've described, because you've already got the serialized the object from the server.

Comment: I don't need the List anymore after I create myBean. I'm just confused because if I want to unit test the class that gets the List and adds myBean to the context I now need to inject a test context into the unit test and Spring documentation says that my objects should be testable without Spring or any other container. I presume this must be quite common in web applications, when a request comes and you need to create objects out of the request.

Comment: I am aware that creating objects within the scope of the method is ok, but this is an object that I will need to pass around many classes.

Comment: "... don't need the List anymore after I create myBean..." - sorry, I'm not following you.  Your comment talks about testing and web apps.  Which is it?  Which one are you most concerned with in your question?

Comment: I would say that it's probably a mistake to be passing a raw List around.  Where's the encapsulation with that?  If one object owns it, give it the means to maintain it and pass *that* around.